# What happens as the stable orbital velocity approaches the speed of light?

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, orbital-motion, geodesics

Based on my understanding of the relationship between planetary mass, orbital radius and the velocity for stable orbit, a satellite orbiting a mass equivalent to Earth with an altitude of ~5mm would have an orbital velocity of $c$.

Clearly this is a classical equation so what would actually happen if you tried to do this? Or does physics conveniently make this a non-question - whereby 5mm is inside the event horizon of an Earth mass, for instance?

Comment: New here, can't comment. This is just some thought. Your question comes from the fact that you are thinking in terms of a theory where speed does not have the upper limit. In this sense, at least you are not inconsistent. The correct approach is, of course, the general relativity where the theory itself is covariant in the sense that your worry is taken care of "automatically" by the consistency of the theroy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want a complete and consistent picture, I would recommend studying geodesics (orbits) in some black-hole solution of equations of GR (for reasons of simplicity, take the Schwarzschild metric). Almost all work is already done for you in this [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarzschild_geodesics).

Short answer: no, the speed would never reach or exceed the speed of light. The aspects of particle dynamics and corrections to the gravitational potential from General Relativity wouldn't allow that to happen.